# COINS - SPOJ TLE in File reading Method

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, eof

Solving the question by Memoization without the help of Maps, I got a TLE due to the method of reading the file, which shouldn't have been the case according to me. What could be the possible reason?

Here is the code that gives AC - http://ideone.com/OX1XlD

In the above code, for scanning n, if the `while(scanf("%lld",&n)!=EOF)` is replaced by

```
         scanf("%lld",&n)
         while(n!=EOF){ do something

                scanf("%lld",&n);
          }
```

the same gives a TLE. I can't figure out why.

Comment: What do you mean with "Maps"? What is TLE? You should not use abbreviations not know everywhere. If that is not required for the question, just do not include - TMI.

Comment: @Olaf Just to add sir, KKDPMAP and CMVK. :-)

Comment: TLE:Time Limit Exceeded

Comment: @SouravGhosh: WTF AKüFi? :-)

Comment: @Olaf Yes, yes, YMMV.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Hmm, for "KKDPMAP" I only get this post from gg, nothing for "CMVK" (but results for CMYK). Do not forget: I'm not a native speaker and English is mostly not used IRL here either.

Comment: @Olaf ermm.. those are [Bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language) abbreviations sir, you won't find them on net I guess. Sorry, I did not foresee that you'll end up searching for those. I added them just for fun :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: LOL! "AKüFi" is actually German: litterally "abbreviation mania" (Well, I always try to enhance my langauge skills)

Comment: http://www.kodemonk.com/lastdig-the-last-digit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check your code in the link, but from the code in the question, in case of `while(scanf("%lld",&n)!=EOF)`, you're checking the return value of `scanf()` itself.

OTOH, by saying

```
   scanf("%lld",&n)
     while(n!=EOF){
```

you're checking the value of `n`, which,  is a completely different case and in case of `scanf()` failure, is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), if `n` is not initialized earlier.

The correct and preferred method,<sup>Thanks to Mr. Weather Vane</sup> will be to check against the number of items in `scanf()`, like

```
if (1 != scanf("%lld",&n))
```

or,

```
while ( 1 == scanf("%lld",&n))  //as in this case
```

`EOF` is a corner case and is usually rare.

Comment: @Olaf Still confised sir. `while(scanf("%lld",&n)!=EOF)` is checking the returned value, right?

Comment: My bad! I did overead the first snippet and confuse with the OPs modification (likely because of "you're", as the he did not use that, but the modified version. Sorry again!

Comment: I suggest you point out the correct method: `while (1 != scanf(...))`. The value `EOF` is only returnd by `scanf` if you give it a `NULL` pointer for the format.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Wouldn't then be `while ( scanf(...) == 1 )` be the correct way? Best, of course to differentiate between `EOF` and `!= 1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Review requested sir.

Comment: @Olaf yes of course thanks, `while (1 == scanf(...))`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Correct me if I'm wrong. So what I make of it is that scanf returns the number of items that have been scanned for a successful input, else an EOF. Since my code requires 1 input in each iteration, so return value for scanf remains 1. As long as this condition is satisfied, the program runs.
What I did earlier was a comparison b/w wrong entities, so even though the 1st condition, ie n!=EOF was satisfied and the program showed the correct output for all n != EOF, as soon as EOF was encountered an unexpected behavior occurred which might have sent the program beyond the time limit.

Comment: Using `while (1 == scanf("%lld",&n))` will catch the corner cases too. My earlier comment error was due to attempting to edit `if (1 != ....)` to `while (1 == ...)`

Answer (score 0):

In response to a recent comment by OP I suggest he tries this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long long int n;
    char instr[20];
    while (1 == scanf("%lld", &n)) {
        printf ("The entry was %lld\n", n);
    }
    printf("End of file\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The SPOJ will test your code by feeding it input from a file. Let's say `inp.txt` has

```
1
2
3
4
```

You then run your code with something like (in the case of Windows console)

```
coins <inp.txt
```

and this gives me the output

```
The entry was 1
The entry was 2
The entry was 3
The entry was 4
End of file
```

If this works, and your program still exceeds the time limit, you must look at your solution algorithm, since SPOJ gives no clues as to *why* you have a TLE.

Of course, your submitted solution must not print those cues since the output will fail the test.